# Using execute_async_script in the Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, selenium, webdriver

I would like to use the execute_async_script command (in the Selenium remote webdriver) to execute some JS with a callback.

I have something similar to this in my current setup for the selenium.selenium model:

```
self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:8000")
```

But how do I use the WebDriver implementation alongside selenium.selenium so I can call execute_async_script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the remote control setup right now, yes?  You should be able to instantiate a WebDriver instance from within that code, but you need to reference the WebDriver dlls.  You will need to instantiate an instance of a browser driver object (ie: FirefoxDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver, etc..) and then set your IWebDriver "driver" property equal to that instance.  Then create an interface object named "js" (or whatever you'd like) as an IJavaScriptExecutor object and call the non-static method "ExecuteScript" or "ExecuteAsyncScript" (in your case).

My code below is in C#.NET (assuming you're using NUnit).  You'll have to find the Python implementation since I don't know that language.

**Class data members:**

```
private IWebDriver driver;
private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
private string baseURL;
```

**Code:**

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxProfile());
baseURL = "http://???";  // replace "???" with website domain
ISelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseURL);
selenium.Start();

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("$('#id').click();");  // assumes JQuery is used in page
js.ExecuteAsyncScript(...);
```

For Python, you can have a look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066902/20443541)