# Understanding execute async script in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been using `selenium` (with [python bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and through [`protractor`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) mostly) for a rather long time and every time I needed to execute a javascript code, I've used `execute_script()` method. For example, [for scrolling the page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page) (python):

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Or, for [infinite scrolling inside an another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794316/protractor-scrolling-a-table-and-testing-for-infinite-scroll) (protractor):

```
var div = element(by.css('div.table-scroll'));
var lastRow = element(by.css('table#myid tr:last-of-type'));

browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].offsetTop;", lastRow.getWebElement()).then(function (offset) {
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];', div.getWebElement(), offset).then(function() {
        // assertions

    });
});
```

Or, for getting a [dictionary of all element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307131/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-find-all-of-an-elements-attributes) (python):

```
driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', element)
```

---

But, WebDriver API also has [`execute_async_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_async_script) which I haven't personally used.

What use cases does it cover? When should I use `execute_async_script()` instead of the regular `execute_script()`?

<sup>The question is selenium-specific, but language-agnostic.</sup>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the [reference](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) to the two APIs (well it's Javadoc, but the functions are the same), and here's an excerpt from it that highlights the difference

> [executeAsyncScript] Execute an asynchronous piece of JavaScript in
>   the context of the currently selected frame or window. Unlike
>   executing synchronous JavaScript, scripts executed with this method
>   must explicitly signal they are finished by invoking the provided
>   callback. This callback is always injected into the executed function
>   as the last argument.

Basically, execSync blocks further actions being performed by the selenium browser, while execAsync does not block and calls on a `callback` when it's done.

---

Since you've worked with protractor, I'll use that as example. 
Protractor uses `executeAsyncScript` in both [`get`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L473) and [`waitForAngular`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L276)

In `waitForAngular`, protractor needs to wait until angular announces that all events settled. You can't use `executeScript` because that needs to return a value at the end (although I guess you can implement a busy loop that polls angular constantly until it's done). The way it works is that protractor provides a callback, which Angular calls once all events settled, and that requires executeAsyncScript. Code [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L29)

In `get`, protractor needs to poll the page until the global `window.angular` is set by Angular. One way to do it is `driver.wait(function() {driver.executeScript('return window.angular')}, 5000)`, but that way protractor would pound at the browser every few ms. Instead, we do this (simplified):

```
functions.testForAngular = function(attempts, callback) {
  var check = function(n) {
    if (window.angular) {
      callback('good');
    } else if (n < 1) {
      callback('timedout');
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {check(n - 1);}, 1000);
    }
  };
  check(attempts);
};
```

Again, that requires `executeAsyncScript` because we don't have a return value immediately. Code [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L519)

---

All in all, use `executeAsyncScript` when you care about a return value in a calling script, but that return value won't be available immediately. This is especially necessary if you can't poll for the result, but must get the result using a callback or promise (which you must translate to callback yourself).

Comment: Thank you for the link to the javaDoc - there are some samples mentioned. Have you personally had a need to execute an async script? If yes, could you describe the use case(s)? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Added some examples. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Great, this was an interesting journey into protractor's client side scripts and other internals! Thanks again. Just in theory let's imagine: if I would test an angular app with selenium python bindings - I would need to load the similar (or same) client-side scripts and call `testForAngular()` and `waitForAngular()` functions asynchronously in order to check and wait for Angular to "become stable". Correct?

Comment: Well, testForAngular just waits for 'window.angular' to be present, and waitForAngular uses 'window.angular' to check if the app is stable, so you definitely need them both, but you'll need a lot of other code too =)

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) I'm just trying to think of a valid real-world non-protractor/angular related example usage of the executeAsyncScript which could not be solved with anything else as easily as with it. FYI, I'll keep this topic open for a while (we'll also start a bounty in a couple of days to draw attention).

Comment: Your reference link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 37):

> When should I use `execute_async_script()` instead of the regular `execute_script()`?

When it comes to checking conditions on the browser side, **all checks you can perform with `execute_async_script` can be performed with `execute_script`. Even if what you are checking is asynchronous.** I know because once upon a time there was a bug with `execute_async_script` that made my tests fail if the script returned results too quickly. As far as I can tell, the bug is gone now so I've been using `execute_async_script` but for months beforehand, I used `execute_script` for tasks where `execute_async_script` would have been more natural. For instance, performing a check that requires loading a module with RequireJS to perform the check:

```
driver.execute_script("""
// Reset in case it's been used already.
window.__selenium_test_check = undefined;
require(["foo"], function (foo) {
    window.__selenium_test_check = foo.computeSomething();
});
""")

result = driver.wait(lambda driver: 
    driver.execute_script("return window.__selenium_test_check;"))
```

The `require` call is asynchronous. The problem with this though, besides leaking a variable into the global space, is that it multiplies the network requests. Each `execute_script` call is a network request. The `wait` method works by polling: it runs the test until the returned value is true. This means one network request per check that `wait` performs (in the code above).

When you test locally it is not a big deal. If you have to go through the network because you are having the browsers provisioned by a service like Sauce Labs (which I use, so I'm talking from experience), each network request slows down your test suite. **So using `execute_async_script` not only allows writing a test that looks more natural (call a callback, as we normally do with asynchronous code, rather than leak into the global space) but it also helps the performance of your tests.**

```
result = driver.execute_async_script("""
var done = arguments[0];
require(["foo"], function (foo) {
    done(foo.computeSomething());
});
""")
```

The way I see it now is that if a test is going to hook into asynchronous code on the browser side to get a result, I use `execute_async_script`. If it is going to do something for which there is no asynchronous method available, I use `execute_script`.

Comment: Superb. +1 for going into detail about when it is still appropriate to use `execute` over `executeAsync`. I would add the caveat: this bug has, for me (using selenium web driver and javascript) seemingly returned.

Comment: What is the callback though and why aren't you passing it?

Comment: @pguardiario The callback is created and passed by Selenium itself. When you use `execute_async_script`, the last argument available on the JavaScript side is the callback created by Selenium. Suppose you call `driver.execute_async_script(script, "foo", "bar")`. In the code that runs in `script`, `arguments[0]` is the value "foo", `arguments[1]` is the value "bar" and `arguments[2]` is the callback that Selenium created. Your script must call the callback when it is done to signal to Selenium that it is done. Otherwise, Selenium cannot know that it is done.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I thought I was supposed to be passing a callback.