# Protractor: best way to wait for custom event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

In my test case, using protractor, I have to wait for a custom event.

My actual way to wait is inject a temporary function that changes a boolean and then wait for that boolean to change.
In other words:

```
browser.executeScript('window.on("customEvent", function(){ 
    window.hasBeenTriggered=true;
  })
)')
browser.driver.wait(function(){
   return browser.executeScript('return window.hasBeenTriggered;'     )===true;
 });
```

Is there a better way to wait for custom event in protractor?
How do you wait for custom event?
Does protractor's API offer a method for doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Read my answer here about [execute_async_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium/28057738#28057738)

```
browser.execute_async_script(
  function(callback) {
    window.on("customEvent", callback(e));
  }
).then(function(e) {
  console.log('custom event called with message: ' + e.message);
});
```