# Getting current video tag URL with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-video

I'm trying to get the current html5 video tag URL using selenium (with python bindings):

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x6YclsLHN0')

video = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('video')
url = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].currentSrc;", video)
print url

driver.quit()
```

The problem is that *the `url` value is printed empty*. Why is that and how can I fix it?

---

I suspect that this is because the script is executed and the `currentSrc` value is returned *before the video tag has been initialized*. I've tried to add an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits), but still got an empty string printed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
video = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'video')))
```

Which makes me feel *I need to do it [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)*. May be listening for the [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) and wait for the `video` to start playing.

I'm also pretty sure `currentSrc` should work, because if I execute the code in the console and manually wait for a video to start - I see it printing the video `currentSrc` attribute value.

---

FYI, also tried with java bindings, same result, an empty string:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x6YclsLHN0");

WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.tagName("video"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String url = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].currentSrc;", video);

System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: I tried it in java, it is working for me. Why are you going for `currentSrc` when you can get the same from `src` attribute of video?

Comment: @VivekSingh thank you, I've updated the question. When I use `src`, I'm still getting an empty string also. See the note about running it from the console also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [W3 video tag specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/video.html#location-of-the-media-resource):

> The currentSrc DOM attribute is initially the empty string. Its value
>   is changed by the resource selection algorithm.

Which explains the behavior described in the question. This also means that to get the `currentSrc` value reliably, we need to **wait until the media resource has it defined**.

Subscribing to the [`loadstart` media event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) through [`execute_async_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_async_script) did the trick:

```
driver.set_script_timeout(10) 

url = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var video = arguments[0],
        callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

    video.addEventListener('loadstart', listener);

    function listener() {
        callback(video.currentSrc);
    };
""", video)
print(url)
```