# How to get Asynchronous Javascript responses from Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, asynchronous, webdriver

We have added an *asynchronious javascript* call to our website.  I'm trying to get Selenium *Webdriver* to wait for a response from the call.

The listener looks like this:

```
$(document).on("application:subapp:rendered", function(){console.log("foo");});
```

My *webdriver* code (python):

```
driver.set_script_timeout(30)
response =  driver.execute_async_script("$(document).on(\"application:subapp:rendered\", function(){return \"foo\";});"
```

Next I execute the page should make "foo" return

however this is my response...

> TimeoutException: Message: asynchronous script timeout: result was not recei
>       ved in 30 seconds
>         (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.118)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d532
>       1e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Answer (score 12):

When you call `execute_async_script`, Selenium passes as the last argument to the JavaScript code the callback you must call to indicate that the asynchronous code is done executing, if you do not pass arguments after your script when you call `execute_async_script`, then this will be accessible as `arguments[0]` in the JavaScript. Whatever value you pass to this callback is what your `execute_async_script` will return so:

```
response = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var done = arguments[0];
    $(document).one('application:subapp:rendered', 
        function(){
           done('foo');
    });
""")
```

In the code above I assign the callback to `done`. That's just the way I like to do it. Note how the value to which `response` will be set is set by calling `done("foo")`.

Note also that I'm using `.one()` rather than `.on()`. I've discovered that Selenium (at least up to 2.45) does not ever consider an old callback created for `execute_async_script` to be "obsolete" so if there is any chance that your event can happen *again* after your JavaScript above has finished executing, then it will call the callback again, and Selenium will honor the call again. If you happen to have another `execute_async_script` running at that time, then this spurious call will terminate your *other* `execute_async_script` call with the return value "foo". I've had that happen in one of my test suites. It led to very bizarre failures.

Comment: Dublicate answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066902/20443541

Answer (score 2):

Use `arguments[0]` as a callback:

```
driver.execute_async_script("""
    $(document).on('application:subapp:rendered', arguments[0]);
""")
```

See also (should help in understanding):

- [Understanding execute async script in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)

Comment: @user3249517 thanks, please accept Louis's answer - it's more detailed and complete.