# Is it possible to resolve promise within the 'executeScript'?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, webdriverjs

I am trying to write my first test using Protractor+Jasmine for my non Angular application.

I need call API function of my app global instance, get result and compare it in test. One of passed in parameters for this function is a callback which is called as soon as data are ready. This function is executed some time depend on configuration of app.

I tried to resolve promise object inside this callback function and handle it in test. This is a simplified version of my code and it also doesn't work. Looks like script `arguments[0].fulfill("Some data");` is never executed because test was failed by timeout with message:

> timed out after 10000msec waiting for spec to complete

```
describe('Text', function() {
    it('should be displayed on stage with set value', function() {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        browser.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].fulfill("Some data");', deferred);
    });
});
```

Is it at all possible to resolve (fulfill) a promise object inside context of function `executeScript()`? Are there other ways to handle this issue?

**UPD:** This code works for me. Thanks!

```
describe('Text', function() {
    it('should be displayed on stage with set value', function() {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

        browser.driver.executeAsyncScript(function () {
            var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

            MyApp.apiFunction({
                callback: function (callbackParams) {
                    callback(callbackParams);
                }
            });
        }, function (data) { // Callback
            deferred.fulfill(data);
        }).then(function (result) {
            // Do what you need with data...
            console.log('Result: ', result);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`executeAsyncScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript) is specifically what you need.

Quoting @hankduan from the [Understanding execute async script in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium) topic:

> **use executeAsyncScript when you care about a return value in a calling
>   script, but that return value won't be available immediately.** This is
>   especially necessary if you can't poll for the result, but must get
>   the result using a callback or promise (which you must translate to
>   callback yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine has an async resole called done
So if you would pass it as deferred than I think it should work

```
 it('should be displayed on stage with set value', function(done) {
 browser.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].fulfill("Some data");', function()

    {
 Object.defineProperty(this, "promise", {
          get: function () { done() },
          enumerable: true
      });


done()
});
```