# Selenium using javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to make selenium pause/hold util next JavaScript event.
For Example :

If i design same login page as Gmail with user name ,password and a button.
with selenium test case, it will fill username ,password and submit.

but what i want is, if i put user name in mytextbox so on focuslost event i want to fill the same textbox on gmail page,same with password, and if i click on login button on my page then it should also perform click event on main gmail page.

Is it possible..? running selenium on specific events?

Plz share any which will be helpful

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Do you want Selenium to click the login button on Gmail?

Comment: I want to create a remote controller.if i click on my button it should also click on gmail login button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JavascriptExecutor` and `executeScript` method it pauses all execution after until the result is returned. There are good amount of [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium) on StackOverflow regarding the difference between `executeScript` and `executeAsyncScript` which can help you in this case.

And, the `Java` api doc is [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)