# How to call the callback function within selenium execute_async_script from python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

i am scraping one website, there is audio playing from the webpage, i want to know when will the audio finish playing, so i add event listener to the audio webElement to monitor 'onEnded' event to fire, and i want to get noticed from the callback() function within driver.execute_async_script.

but i always get error

`TypeError: <function MissionContentItemHelper.audio_play_end at 0x10f3b7b70> is not JSON serializable.`

my questions are:

1.does arguments[arguments.length - 1] refer to self.audio_play_end ?

2.why the error output is about 'MissionContentItemHelper.audio_play_end is not JSON serializable'? i can't see any clue between MissionContentItemHelper.audio_play_end and JSON.

3.is the way calling audio_play_end correct?

```
class MissionContentItemHelper: 
    def sleep(self):
        audio = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#audio')
        self.browser.execute_async_script("""
            var audio = arguments[0];
            callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            audio.addEventListener("ended", function(_event) {
                callback();
            }
        """, audio, self.audio_play_end)

    @staticmethod
    def audio_play_end():
        print('the audio finished playing...')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding execute async script in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

`execute_async_script`'s name confuses many people. It doesn't executes the script asynchronously from your test code, it only allows you to execute a script which runs asynchronously from the browser's main thread, like AJAX calls and JavaScript `setTimeout`.

These JavaScript functions and alike themselves return almost immediately, but they take a (JavaScript) function argument that is executed when the asynchronous operation completes. What `execute_async_script` does is exactly like `execute_script`, but instead of returning when the function itself returns (which is almost immediately) it provides its own callback JavaScript function (which it passes as the last argument, that's why the `arguments[arguments.length - 1]` is needed), that you can use in the JavaScript code you're passing into `execute_async_script`, to pass it on to the asynchronous function as the callback. `execute_async_script` returns only when this callback is called, instead of returning immediately.

For example, in the following code, the call to `execute_async_script` acts like a delay of 2 seconds:

`browser.execute_async_script("setTimeout(arguments[0], 2000)")`

Note that because I didn't pass any additional arguments to the script, then `arguments[0]` is actually the last argument.

In your case, you don't have to pass `self.audio_play_end`, but you have to call `audio.play()` inside your JavaScript snippet to start the audio. `execute_async_script` should return only when the audio is finished playing.

Answer (score 0):

Usage works as following:

```py
# driver allready i initialised

js = """
     var done = arguments[0];
     // my_async_acript here ..
        .then(value=>done(value)
"""
value = driver.execute_async_script(js)
```

Call javascript function `done(value)` with the value you want to **return**.

Note: If you're getting a timeout-exception, check the developer-console for errors

This actually is a dublicate I think [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066902/20443541)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know that the last argument passed is the promise resolver. That means:

```
self.browser.execute_async_script("""
  let [element, resolve] = arguments
  element.addEventListener("ended", resolve)    
""", audio)
```